# How to send HTML mails using Amazon SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

How to send HTML mails using Amazon SNS? or do I need to use SES for that?
I went through the documentation but it seems there is no way to send HTML mails using Amazon SNS.

Answer (score 11):

You can use Amazon SES to **send** the emails and SNS to **trigger** the sending process.

Suppose you have an app `http://myapp.com` where the endpoint `/api/send-email` takes care of sending HTML email trough Amazon SES.

You set up an Amazon SNS topic, **subscribe** the endpoint `/api/send-email` to receive notifications and when something happens, the notification will **trigger** the email.

You can setup `/api/send-email` to take parameters from the JSON data stored in the notification and send the email using that information.

Comment: @Wrench you have to create a **subscription** : fill in the _Topic ARN_ by the one you want, **platform** is _HTTP_ and **Endpoint** is the URL where you will be notified. On your server (which deserves the URL) you have to contact Amazon SES to send an email for the subscriber.