# Sending html content in AWS SNS(Simple Notification Service) emails notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using **AWS SNS**(Simple Notification Service) to send email notifications. In the content of the email, I have to represent data in tabular form. Currently I am using **simple text string** to print the table but that has **formatting issues** when the email is accessed through smaller screen devices like mobile and tablets, and the tabular data is just impossible to interpret. I wish to use html table instead of simple string table as html can be rendered more adequately by all size devices. 
So I want to represent my data in **html table** and want this table to be **rendered** by the email client, whatever it may be.
Can this be done using **AWS SNS**?

Comment: Please check the below link if this helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201837/how-to-send-html-mails-using-amazon-sns

Comment: See also, in my answer to your prior question from a few hours prior to this one: [*"You can't even send HTML emails."*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32214877/1695906)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Amazon SNS is designed to distribute notifications.** These can be received in a variety of formats, such as email, SMS, messages pushed to HTTP endpoints, mobile phone notifications and even triggering of AWS Lambda functions.

**It is *not* designed as a fully-featured email system.** It will only send text messages and appends an 'unsubscribe' footer at the bottom of the messages.

If you wish to send formatted emails, consider using **Amazon Simple Email Service (SES)**, which improves email deliverability. Any content passed into Amazon SES is sent out to recipients, including HTML.

Amazon SNS is primarily about notification, rather than pretty content.

Comment: Ability to have a Html link in SNS is a reasonable feature to ask from AWS

Comment: @SathiyaS As a workaround one can simply put a URL in the message and most of the email clients will convert it to a link anyways.

Comment: @SathiyaS agreed that templates are not an unreasonable thing for SNS to support. Maybe some day it will, but now it doesn't.