# Send Hyperlink in SNS publish message using python

Tags: python, amazon-sns, boto3

I have a requirement to send the hyperlink to a url stored in a variable via sns using python . With my current code I am able to send the entire link but its not sending the hyperlink .Can anyone suggest solution on how can I send the hyperlink in email via sns .

```
s3Client=boto3.client('s3')
    object=s3Client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',Params=    {'Bucket':'eds-illuminati-dev','Key': f})


response = client.publish(
    TargetArn='XXXXXX',
    Subject="Mismatch in Fees Calculated",
   # Message="""Click on the link to download the file\n"{0}" \n>link"""     .format(object)
     Message='<a href={0}>link</a>' .format(object)
    )
print("response={}".format(response))
```

Comment: Still it gives me the same result , it give me the hyperlink to the url .

Comment: Check this [Sending HTML content in AWS SNS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241928/sending-html-content-in-aws-snssimple-notification-service-emails-notification)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending html content in AWS SNS(Simple Notification Service) emails notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241928/sending-html-content-in-aws-snssimple-notification-service-emails-notification)

Comment: The above link does not provide a solution, rather a link that SNS doesn't provide this feature. Being able to provide a simple Html link in SNS is a reasonable feature one can expect.