# Can you add style to sns email messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Can you bold some letters, change font, etc... Maybe format with html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS SNS is designed for basic text "push" style notification email. AWS SES is a more full featured mail sender.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241928/sending-html-content-in-aws-snssimple-notification-service-emails-notification).

AWS FAQ [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/#11).