# Monospaced font with Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-sns

I am using Python boto3 to publish a message with SNS.  I want to send tabular data as plain text so it appears as rows and columns.  But my emails are being sent with regular font, so the columns don't line up.  Is there a way to make it use monospaced font?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending html content in AWS SNS(Simple Notification Service) emails notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241928/sending-html-content-in-aws-snssimple-notification-service-emails-notification)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon SNS sends plain-text messages with no formatting. Any formatting would be provided by your email client (eg choice of font).

If you wish to send a formatted message, you could write an AWS Lambda function that is triggered by the SNS message, then use Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) to send a formatted message.