# AWS Code Commit Slack Integration - Display author and commit details

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, slack, aws-codecommit

I just setup Slack integration of AWS codecommit. Where I received only repository name and branch. Additonally I also want to know who made this commit and commit message.

[image]

I did try to setup Input transformer rule. Now It shows two role in Amazon EventBridge.

[image]

I have added below input target json. But nothing happens.

```
{
    "author" : "$.detail.author",
    "repositories" : "$.detail.respositoryNames"
}
```

[This is already ask question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011496/aws-code-commit-slack-integration-how-to-display-author-and-commit-message) but there is no proper answer to this question.

Comment: It's possible that there's no "proper answer" (what would a "proper answer" be?) because there is no way to do it. I'm not saying that there is or is not, just that this is not a good sign. Note that Git itself cannot help you directly as Git does not implement AWS notifications.

Comment: I have manage to achieve what I want with Lambda python function. I created a slack app from slack web and generated a webhook url. I need to paste that webhook url into the lambda function script and set couple of permission to lambda function and voila.. it worked. I will post more details answer in few hours.

Answer (score 4):

So instead of AWS chat with slack I have managed to make it work with AWS Lambda with python 3.7 script.

You need to create a private/public channel in your slack so that all those commit feed will display there. I have created a private channel. Then create a slack app by follwing below steps.

How to Create a Slack Incoming Webhook URL?

Further in this article, you will require a Slack Incoming Webhook URL to connect your AWS SNS to Slack. Follow the steps below to Create a Slack Incoming Webhook URL from scratch:

**Step 1:** The first step involved in connecting SNS to Slack requires you to create a Slack App. You can get started by clicking this link – [Slack API: Applications](https://api.slack.com/apps?new_app=1).

**Step 2:** Enable Incoming Webhooks for connecting SNS to Slack. To do so, go to Settings → Incoming Webhooks → Activate Incoming Webhooks. Your page will get refreshed.

**Step 3:** Create an Incoming Webhook by clicking on Add New Webhook to Workspace.

**Step 4:** Pick your desired Channel to post your messages from SNS to Slack and click on Authorize.

**Step 5:** You’ll be redirected to your app settings, where you should now notice a new entry under the Webhook URLs for your Workspace section, with a Webhook URL that looks like this:

https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXX

[image]

You need to copy that webhook url and go to AWS Lambda to create a python 3.7 code.

Lambda python 3.7 code

```
import json
import boto3
import urllib3

codecommit = boto3.client('codecommit')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Log the updated references from the event
    references = {reference['ref'] for reference in event['Records'][0]['codecommit']['references']}
    print("References: " + str(references))
    # Get the repository from the event and show its git clone URL
    repository = event['Records'][0]['eventSourceARN'].split(':')[5]

    try:
        user = event['Records'][0]['userIdentityARN'].split(':')[5].split('/')[1]
        references = event['Records'][0]['codecommit']['references']
        for reference in references:
            commit = reference['commit']
            branch = reference['ref'].split('/')[2]
            commit_resp = codecommit.get_commit(repositoryName=repository, commitId=commit)
            message = commit_resp['commit']['message']
            parent_commit = commit_resp['commit']['parents'][0]
            commit_name = commit_resp['commit']['author']['name']
            diff_resp = codecommit.get_differences(
                repositoryName=repository,
                beforeCommitSpecifier=parent_commit,
                afterCommitSpecifier=commit
            )
            files = ''
            i = 1
            for blobs in diff_resp['differences']:
                files = files + f'\n\t{blobs["afterBlob"]["path"]}'
                i = i+1
                if i > 4:
                    files = files + f'\n\t ...more files'
                    break

            webhook = 'paste your webhook url here.'
            data = {
                "text": f"  <@{commit_name}> (<@{user}>) committed code to {branch} branch of {repository} \nCommit message : {message} \nCommit Id: {commit} \nFiles:{files}"}

            http = urllib3.PoolManager()
            r = http.request("POST", webhook,
                             body=json.dumps(data),
                             headers={"Content-type": "application/json"})

        return 'Success'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(
            'Error getting repository {}. Make sure it exists and that your repository is in the same region as this function.'.format(repository))
        raise e
```

Update your webhook url here.

`webhook = 'paste your webhook url here.'`

After that add a trigger for Lambda function to codecommit.

[image]

Also do add permission for lambda function to access codecommit. After that every commit you will see feed in your channel.

[image]

Comment: Your recommendation is great, however my Lambda got stucked and timed out when trying to gather these details:
" commit = reference['commit']
   branch = reference['ref'].split('/')[2]
    commit_resp = codecommit.get_commit(repositoryName=repository, commitId=commit)
           message = commit_resp['commit']['message']
            parent_commit = commit_resp['commit']['parents'][0]
            commit_name = commit_resp['commit']['author']['name']"

Comment: maybe check logs where it is stuck. Or share the logs report to check. Maybe some property is missing.